# Docker port mapping issue

Tags: docker

Simple docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8u151
EXPOSE 8080:8080
ADD /target/myJar.jar myJar.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "myJar.jar"]
```

Docker run command:

```
docker run myjar-image -p 8080:8080
```

Docker ps:

```
PORTS
8080/tcp
```

It should be:

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

There is no indication of an error (silent failure).  Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker-specific options come *before* the image name.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 myjar-image
```

Anything passed *after* the image name is interpreted as the "command" and passed as additional arguments to the entrypoint; as you've launched it your container actually starts (with no published ports)

```
java -jar myJar.jar -p 8080:8080
```

which could in principle be useful but isn't what you're trying for here.